# Send value to one input and then in the other from slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have one slider and two inputs.

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<input type="number" id="firstInput">
<input type="text" id="secondInput">
```

If I change slider value second input will be changed and after this I need to update my last input in real time.

```
$(function(){
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 100,
    max: 1000,
    value: 600,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#firstInput" ).val( ui.value );
      $(ui.value).val($('#firstInput').val());
   }
  });
    $( "#firstInput" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
    $('#firstInput').bind('change paste keyup', function() {
      $( "#slider" ).slider( "value", $('#firstInput').val() );
    });
    $(document).click(function() {
       $('#secondInput').val($('#firstInput').val());
    });
});
```

I thought the change event would help, but not.

[Example in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Frunky/wtp2qubv/)

Comment: _after this I need to update my last input in real time_.. Could you please elaborate this?

Comment: If I change value in slider second input will be updated, I need to update last input with same value. While I do not click on the first input, nothing will happen, but I need to update last input in real time without any click

Comment: You are confusing the question buddy.. As per my observation, if you change `value` in slider `$( "#firstInput" )` gets updated right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update The Code

html

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<input type="number" id="firstInput">
<input type="number" id="secondInput">
```

jquery

```js
$(function(){
 $( "#slider" ).slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 100,
    max: 1000,
    value: 600,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#firstInput" ).val( ui.value );
      $(ui.value).val($('#firstInput').val());
      $( "#secondInput" ).val( ui.value );
      $(ui.value).val($('#firstInput').val());
    }
  });
  $( "#firstInput" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
  
  $('#firstInput').bind('change paste keyup', function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider( "value", $('#firstInput').val() );
 }); $('#secondInput').bind('change paste keyup', function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider( "value", $('#firstInput').val() );
 });
  $( "#secondInput" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
  $(document).click(function() {
   $('#secondInput').val($('#firstInput').val());
       $('#firstInput').val($('#secondInput').val());

 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you just need to update both inputs at the same time?

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 100,
        max: 1000,
        value: 600,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#firstInput, #secondInput").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#firstInput, #secondInput").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
});
```

Or even this rather?

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 100,
        max: 1000,
        value: 600,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#firstInput, #secondInput").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#firstInput, #secondInput").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
    $('#firstInput, #secondInput').bind('change paste keyup', function() {
        $("#slider").slider("value", $(this).val());
        $("#firstInput, #secondInput").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```